# Using sequence while inserting data into 2 tables at same time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert data using select statement. The table which I am inserting is having foreign key and it is sequence ID. How do I accomplish this? Because if I insert the sequence key in associated table first then how do I get the list of all the sequence ID to insert into the table.
Please note I am using insert with select statement so is there way to accomplish this without using cursor?

Comment: Use the `OUTPUT INTO` clause to insert into the other table, or into a table variable

Comment: Do you use "Sequence" or your tables have "identity" column, which you want to have identical?

Comment: @slava I am using sequence. This sequence is again referred in another table as a foreign key. How can I handle this

Comment: @anonymous13b as the first comment says, use the `output` clause. That is your answer. If you had some actual code in your question, someone might assist you adding the output clause - so long as you have a go yourself of course.

Comment: @dale I am using sql server database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what I have tried.

```
DECLARE @MyTabVaR TABLE
(
FOREIGNKEY_ID INT,
COMMON_COL INT
);

INSERT INTO @MyTabVaR
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR DBO.MY_SEQ,COMMON_COL FROM another_table2

INSERT INTO actual_table 
SELECT FOREIGNKEY_ID FROM @MyTabVaR

INSERT INTO another_table 
SELECT * FROM copy_table C
LEFT JOIN actual_table A
ON C.COMMON_COL=A.COMMON_COL
WHERE A.FOREIGNKEY_ID IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can extract sequence value and then re-use it as many times as you want:

```
DECLARE @NextValue INT
SELECT @NextValue = NEXT VALUE FOR MySequence
SELECT NextValue = @NextValue
INSERT INTO PrimaryTable(PK_ID) VALUES (@NextValue);
INSERT INTO SecondaryTable(FK_ID) VALUES (@NextValue);
```

Comment: RBAR? Not much fun if you have a bunch of rows to insert.

Comment: @Slava, I am getting answers for 1 record. The suggestion will work for 1 record, but how do we tackle the scenario where i have to insert the data from another table and it will be set of records? how can i identitfy the sequence which i have to insert in foreign table as a key.

Comment: @DaleK You are absolutely right. That is the nature of a Sequence in  SQL Server. If it is used as Default for PK, then we still can't use OUTPUT INTO because we'll need anoter identifier, other than PK, inserted in primary table to identify records. If that the case, we can do it in a second query, but I'm afraid it is not the case.

Comment: @anonymous13b As mentioned before, you can only get a list of just inserted records via OUTPUT INTO, however, it won't help you a lot.